# NEED help about Android application

Tags: android, matlab

i am developing an application using optical character recognition (OCR) for android system Mobiles.

1. Can we convert the Matlab program is Android Application ?
2. if there is any tool for converting the matlab code into Android application. what is the tool name??

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no tool that will allow you to *directly* convert MATLAB code to an Android application; however, MATLAB does provide automatic code generation through their MATLAB Coder product.  This tool allows you to convert your MATLAB functions to C or C++ code.  Similarly, you can convert Simulink models to C/C++ using Simulink Coder.

This [link](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/) has more info on both MATLAB and Simulink Coder.

So perhaps you could develop the core of your algorithm in MATLAB or Simulink, generate C/C++ code, and then integrate this code into your Android application.

Also, I should point out that there is a product called [MATLAB Mobile](http://www.mathworks.com/mobile/), but I believe that this just allows you to access MATLAB running on your desktop from your mobile device.  Furthermore, I believe that only iOS is currently supported.  So I still think that MATLAB/Simulink Coder would be your best bet.